# Android Studio "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from a RoomDB then using a custom adapter to present this data in a recycler view.

But I am occasionally getting this error, "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

This is where the error happens

```
((MyActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            setData();
                                        }
                                    });
```

I don't understand what is from as I am using the context of the activity the recycler view is in and then running the thread on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the task that updates the UI onto the main thread.
Try like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // UI Updates

    }
});
```

Comment: Thats what I have done, the set data function calls "notfyDataSetChanged" which updates the recycler view

Comment: try with this getActivity().runOnUiThread(etc)

Comment: I dont think youve read my question, I am getting the context of the activity already as I am doing this work in the adapter for the view

Comment: Are u sure that the context is a context of the main activity?

Comment: no its not the main activity but the activity that the recycler view is, should I be using the main one?

Comment: I believe yes, could you please check?

Comment: I will try but this error isn't consistent

Comment: Can u also share setData function body?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250260/discussion-between-taron-qalashyan-and-ckhgray).

Comment: Can you share body of setData and logcat error ? that will help

Comment: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            
//Data operations here and then go back to Ui for updates

            runOnUiThread {
                // UI Updates
                buildUI()
            }
        }